# Google Analytics errors in android app sample

Tags: android, google-analytics

I'm new in Google Analytics. I try a tutorial from this link https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/. I've import the Mobile Playground project and also add Google Analytics jar file, but many errors appear. The errors

```
error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'value' with value '@integer/google_play_services_version').    AndroidManifest.xml /MobilePlayground   line 15 Android AAPT Problem
GoogleAnalytics cannot be resolved  AnalyticsSampleApp.java /MobilePlayground/src/com/google/android/gms/analytics/samples/mobileplayground line 48 Java Problem
HitBuilders cannot be resolved to a type    AppviewFragment.java    /MobilePlayground/src/com/google/android/gms/analytics/samples/mobileplayground line 71 Java Problem
GoogleAnalytics cannot be resolved to a type    AnalyticsSampleApp.java /MobilePlayground/src/com/google/android/gms/analytics/samples/mobileplayground line 48 Java Problem
```

I've changed the some import, but still have errors. For the examples, I change `import com.google.android.gms.analytics.GoogleAnalytics;` to `import com.google.analytics.tracking.android.GoogleAnalytics;`

Please, tell me how to fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

This error -

`error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'value' with value '@integer/google_play_services_version').`

is caused because you haven't imported Google play services into your project